# How to get exact frame for text by using custom fonts in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextview, core-text

Please have a look at this image to understand the problem clearly.

[image]

In our application user can enter text, based on the text size we are changing the frame of `textview`. We are getting frame by using `boundingRect` method on the attributed string. But for some fonts ex: Great vibes I am not getting exact frame.

It's giving exact frame for 99% of the fonts. But for few font styles and for few characters not getting proper frame.

```
[string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxAllowedWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{required attributes} context:nil]
```

So to overcome this problem I am trying calculate frame by using Core text framework. There we have an API  `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints()` which gives size. Still this is also not giving exact frame. By using `CTLineGetImageBounds()` I am getting exact frame. But It's giving only for one line.

I need the frame for multiple lines of text.

Comment: What is the issue with `boundingRect ` ??

Comment: It's not giving exact frame

Comment: Actually it gives the exact frame bcz i already tried it with multiple fonts and langs. There must be some other issue. Pls add your code.

Comment: It's giving exact frame for 99% of the fonts. But for few font styles and for few characters not getting proper frame.   [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxAllowedWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{required attributes} context:nil]

Comment: Which font style it is??

Comment: With GreatVibes Font try for Character "T"

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for this,

1=> remove height and width constraint of your label. Then is auto resize according to your text.

2=> Use this function

```
- (CGSize)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text) {
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 1);
    }
    return size;
}
```